# Coloring HTML tags by class with JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a spreadsheet type program out of table cells and AngularJS and I would like to color my input cells based on the user's uploaded file.

I have an array that contains all of the user's data that I iterate through, and pending a match with some regular expressions, some data is pushed into a "red array" and a "blue array". I then have a function that is to be called when the original array's info is put into the spreadsheet. This function checks to see if the info being placed is in either the red or blue array, and will then color the input box red or blue (or green if no match is found.)
This coloring function is supposed to return a string which can be used as either the id or class of the input tag, and in the CSS, it colors the tag based on this returned name.

However, I can't seem to figure out the correct way of coloring the input tag. My input boxes remain the default white.

```
<script>
...

var blue = ["blue1","blue2","blue3"];
var red = ["red1","red2","red3"];
var allData = [["red1","misc1","misc2"],["blue1","blue2","blue3"],["red2","red3","misc3"]];

var makeColors = function(data){
    if( data in red){
        return "red";
    }
    else if( data in blue){
        return "blue";
    }
    else{
        return "green";
    }
};

//creates the spreadsheet       
sheet= function($scope, $parse){
$scope.columns = ["col1","col2","col3"]
$scope.rows = allData.length;
$scope.cells = {};
$scope.values = allData;
};
</script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="sheet">
    <center><table>
        <tr class="column-label">
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column}}</td>
        <tr ng-repeat="value in values">
            <td class="row-label" ng-repeat="data in value">
                <div id="{{data}}">
                    <input type="text" value="{{data}}" class="makeColors({{data}})">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table></center>
</div>

<style>

input{
    font-size: 10pt;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1.2em;
    height: 14pt;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 4pt;
    border: none;
    width: 80px;
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td > div {
    height:16pt;
    width:2px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #0EE;
    width:85px;

}
.column-label >td, .row-label{
    text-align:center;
    background: #EEE;
}
.row-label {
    width: 2em;
}
input.red{
    background-color: red;
}
input.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}
input.green{
    background-color: green;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

`class="makeColors({{data}})"`

You can't do it like that. Here is a fiddle where I'm using a map() to solve it: http://jsfiddle.net/W5aED/

To explain further the problem, the code outside {{ }} is not executed by angular (I mean  the `makeColors(` part)  and even if it were that is not the correct way to execute a javascript function.

Comment: That's just what I needed! Thanks so much.